# WooCommerce - display related products by tags

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I want to display related products based on tags. I tried several method and none of them worked. Does someone knows is there way to force related products to be displayed based on tags (not on category)

Here is code that I used to do that (I add this piece of code inside functions.php):

```
//New "Related Products" function for WooCommerce
function get_related_custom( $id, $limit = 5 ) {
    global $woocommerce;

    // Related products are found from category and tag
    $tags_array = array(0);
    $cats_array = array(0);

    // Get tags
    $terms = wp_get_post_terms($id, 'product_tag');
    foreach ( $terms as $term ) $tags_array[] = $term->term_id;

    // Get categories (removed by NerdyMind)
/*
    $terms = wp_get_post_terms($id, 'product_cat');
    foreach ( $terms as $term ) $cats_array[] = $term->term_id;
*/

    // Don't bother if none are set
    if ( sizeof($cats_array)==1 && sizeof($tags_array)==1 ) return array();

    // Meta query
    $meta_query = array();
    $meta_query[] = $woocommerce->query->visibility_meta_query();
    $meta_query[] = $woocommerce->query->stock_status_meta_query();

    // Get the posts
    $related_posts = get_posts( apply_filters('woocommerce_product_related_posts', array(
        'orderby'        => 'rand',
        'posts_per_page' => $limit,
        'post_type'      => 'product',
        'fields'         => 'ids',
        'meta_query'     => $meta_query,
        'tax_query'      => array(
            'relation'      => 'OR',
            array(
                'taxonomy'     => 'product_cat',
                'field'        => 'id',
                'terms'        => $cats_array
            ),
            array(
                'taxonomy'     => 'product_tag',
                'field'        => 'id',
                'terms'        => $tags_array
            )
        )
    ) ) );
    $related_posts = array_diff( $related_posts, array( $id ));
    return $related_posts;
}
add_action('init','get_related_custom');
```

Answer (score 4):

This should do it for you, but you should add this to `single-product.php` or `/woocommerce/single-product/related.php`

```
<?php
    global $post;

    $cats = wp_get_post_terms( $post->ID, "product_cat" );
    foreach ( $cats as $cat ) {
        $cats_array[] .= $cat->term_id;
    }

    $tags = wp_get_post_terms( $post->ID, "product_tag" );
    foreach ( $tags as $tag ) {
        $tags_array[] .= $tag->term_id;
    }

    $related_posts = new WP_Query(
        array(
            'orderby' => 'rand',
            'posts_per_page' => 5,
            'post_type' => 'product',
            'post__not_in' => array($post->ID),
            'tax_query' => array(
                /*  
                    'relation' => 'OR',
                    array(
                            'taxonomy' => 'product_cat',
                            'field' => 'id',
                            'terms' => $cats_array
                    ),
                */
                    array(
                            'taxonomy' => 'product_tag',
                            'field' => 'id',
                            'terms' => $tags_array
                    )
            )
        ) 
    );
?>
```